# Right div fixed left div scrollable, how to make its height 100%

Tags: css, html

I have left div fixed, and right div scrollable. I have applied height:100% on the right div,but it doesn't work, i made background of the div yellow,and when i scroll it disappears, like it doesn't extend like it should.
Here is my code:

```
#levi{
width:25%;
height:100%;
background-color:#f98765;
position:fixed;
left:0;
float:left;

}

#desni{
background-color:yellow;
left:25%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
left:value;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: You should also display the HTML so we can understand the structure.

Comment: Please submit an example on jsfiddle.net or another test site and add the link to your question. As it stands we cannot answer this without guessing how the rest of the page is laid out.

Comment: I am sorry, here is jsfiddle code http://jsfiddle.net/RBHXE/

Answer (score 0):

One method is to set the background color of your right column on the `<body>` tag. That way, the background color will appear to always cover then entire height of the scroll area.

This is commonly known as ["faux columns"](http://alistapart.com/article/fauxcolumns).

```
body {
    background-color:yellow;
    margin:0;
}
#levi {
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#f98765;
    position:fixed;
}
#desni {
    position:absolute;
    left:25%;
}
```

[Working Example (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7ssGH/2/)

[Updated Working Example (with OPs posted HTML structure)](http://jsfiddle.net/RBHXE/2/)

Comment: i just saw,that now my objects slajd and obj overlap other when i resize the window, can you help me with that? :D

Comment: I don't see them overlapping.. but that issue might be due to using fixed pixel widths on those elements. If you resize your window smaller than `650px`, `div#slajd` won't fit.

Comment: They go over the left div when i resize the window, and scroll to the right. I know about that fixed pixel width, i will fix it, thanks.